# 2 Different jQuery in the same Page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery file that is reqiured for the theme Functions..

```
<script src="/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
```

The other jQuery file is needed to handle table operations:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

Loading the jquery first will allow the theme functions to work, loading the 1.11.1 first will allow the table functions to work. using 
noConflict
Does not help, loading both of the files is not helping. Please Advise

Comment: Check the console for errors and fix them when you use 1.11. You should use a single copy of the latest version of jQuery that's available to you.

Comment: which version of jQueery is the first one

Comment: The first one is jQuery JavaScript Library v2.1.0, console not showing anything.

Comment: What errors do you get? Why does noConflict not work? Why is the first version required for "theme functions"? Why is second required for table operations?

Comment: have you tried using versioin v2.1.0 and adding the migration plugin rather then the old version of jquery. I'm guessing the table functionality requires methods removed from jquery v2.x.x#

Comment: well 1.11.1 needed because it has table functions which seems to be removed from version 2.1.0, and seems like the 2.1.0 got some custom functions from the theme developers. how would i combine them?

Comment: see my answer, there is a official jquery migration plugin that should handle this for you (moving from v1.x to v2.x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When jquery moved from v1.x to v2.x they removed a lot of methods as well as support for older browsers. it's likley that your table code requires methods removed from version 2.x

you should be able to load jquery v2.x and use jqueries migrate plugin to handle any missing functionality, rather then have to load two versions of jquery and deal with the noConflict issue.

you can get the [jquery migrate plugin here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme)

Comment: Also not helping. done the following:

<script src=assets/grocery_crud/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/theme_assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.js"></script>

Comment: no you need to use jquery v2.x with the migrate plugin, not the old version

Comment: I tried loading v2.x first too, nothing changes, maybe i need to include some additional code? however i didn't see anything in the docs..

Comment: can you reproduce it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Hmm but now an error is shown:

JQMIGRATE: jQuery is not compatible with Quirks Mode
jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js:43 console.trace()jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js:43 migrateWarn

Comment: that means your `html` is not valid, it contains an error, most likley the `doctype` try running your html [through a validator](https://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: you are still loading the old v1.x version of jquery in that jsfiddle and there is no doctype, which explains you error, you'd need to fix the html on your page

Comment: Yes I am loading the old after the new with the migrate plugin in between, adding <!DOCTYPE> is removing my left sidebar for somereason, fixing HTML warnings, and I will write back..

Comment: the point of the migrate plugin is that you not need the old version. the plugin adds the functionality that was removed for versions 2.x

Comment: the HTML is Vaild, Added v 2.x first the migration plugin right after, the theme functions doesn't work, added v1.11 after the migration also doesn't work. I tried almost everything and still can't get the functions from jQuery 1.11.1 work togther with v2.x.... any suggestions? no console errors..

Comment: Totally desperate i started to go each .js i am loading one by one to see where is the conflict, and finally i found it:
js/bootstrap/dropdown.min.js
this file caused all my troubles. and from both of the jQuery files to be working togther, finally. problem solved! Thanks to atmd for the time and help!

Comment: I see, so it was the bootstrap plugins that was causing the errors. glad your sorted it